# Tub Shoe tight to tub

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, plumbing-fixture

I have an intermittently leaking tub drain, where it leaks to the ceiling below.  Pulling the drain insert, and replacing the putty with fresh putty seems to help for a while.

However, I was never able to extract the gasket from between the tub and the drain shoe, as it appears to be a very tight fit.  My guess is that things settled, or somehow there is allot of strain on that shoe from support.

Short of pulling the drywall off, and getting at that connection externally, any suggestions or tricks to reduce the pressure between the shoe and the tub so that I can pull the rubber gasket and set a new one?

Comment: You should be able to use a tool to *carefully* press down on the shoe, relieving the tension, whilst simultaneously using a hooked tool to pull the rubber gasket. have you tried this? NOTE- that gasket has little to do with sealing, it is mostly just a cusion between the shoe and tub bottom, providing even squeeze on the putty up top which is the primary seal mechanism.

Comment: Yes, that is what I expected to do.  But the shoe was unyielding, and the pinch on the gasket was tight enough that a small piece of it came off with a tug with the needle nose pliers.  So from your comment, I then assume that replacing the putty every 4 or 5 years is normal?  I suppose using silicone sealant would make a quasi permanent mess which would be hard to disassemble.

Comment: If I don't want the silicone to stick I smear a thin coating on the surface, then apply the silicone and assemble not tight for an hour to let the silicone setup a bit, then tighten, it makes a great gasket and it won't stick where the grease was.